# Android Eclipse: What's the easiest way to duplicate a class?

Tags: android, eclipse, class, android-layout

I am creating several classes that are similar to one I already have.  Right now I right-click the .java file, then select "copy."  After that, I right-click and select "paste."  Then I proceed to modify the file.  I do the same for its corresponding .xml layout file.

I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this?  Perhaps one with some added intelligence to automatically set up the new file(s) semi-automatically?

Comment: Why are you duplicating classes?  Would inheritance be a better option?

Comment: if they're similar, can't you use the same xml file and modify certian elements (text, background, etc) slightly in the java code?

Comment: I'm not looking for an inheritance-based solution at the moment, but merely some easy keyboard/menu shortcuts that Eclipse may have for copying/refactoring.  They're not similar enough to warrant inheritance.  Just trying to saving time/keystrokes/mouseclicks.  Thanks!

Comment: Wish we had something similar to refactor copy in netbeans

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clicking on the file and pressing Ctrl-C will copy the file.  Click on the folder and press Ctrl-V.

Comment: I think this is going to be as close as I'm going to get to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Copying the file to the same folder also automatically changes the class name when you enter the new file name. Handy.

Answer (score 1):

For the classes this article can help you

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

and for the layouts read this one

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

I hope it helps!

Comment: The "reusing layouts" tip looks interesting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any *DUPLICATE* option in the R-Click menu.
But a good old <kbd>CTR+C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> right in eclipse does the job.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a class that you require copy very often... it's perhaps the functionality and behavior that you want in copied classes. It's very easily done using inheritance.

So, make a class that has common functionality as a super class and let all the classes that need those functionality extend it. That's all.

Copying and pasting is not a good idea.. because you will be distributing same logic in multiple file, which will be a pain in case you want to change some behavior -- you will have to edit all the copied files. Inheritance will keep them at one place.

Answer (score 0):

I often need to do this for inner classes, rather than duplicating files. Here's how I do it:

- Open Outline view ( <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> )
- Select inner class in Outline view
- Copy ( <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> )
- Select top-level class
- Paste ( <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> )

This creates a new inner class inside the top level class.